# WKWebView with Cookies (iOS10/Xamarin)

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, cookies, wkwebview

I have to create an application that redirects to a page accessible only to the user. So I have to inject cookies. In iOS 10 version, I used NSHttpCookieStorage and everything worked well but the problem appears in iOS11, because UIWebView does not read JS well and there are problems. UIWebView changed to WKWebView.

- iOS11 version injected cookies using webView.Configuration.WebsiteDataStore.HttpCookieStore.SetCookie ()
  the problem appears in version 10, when WKWebsiteDataStore is not supported: /

I am trying to inject cookies using JS -> WKUserScript but the page does not go any further, I still have a login panel, I added EvaluateScript and continue to do the same, and I have no idea how to do it: /

**HybridWebView.cs**

```
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<HybridWebView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control == null)
        {
            userController = new WKUserContentController();
            var script = new WKUserScript(new NSString(JavaScriptFunction), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentStart, false);

            userController.AddScriptMessageHandler(this, "updateCookies");
            string p = "document.cookie = 'IsXamarin=true'; document.cookie = '.GTMS_AUTH=YTJlOGE2MTktYmQzZC00NmZmLTlmMzctZDY2ZjBmOWM2YjQw'; domain = '10.10.208.219'; path = '/'; ";

            NSHttpCookie cookie2 = new NSHttpCookie(".GTMS_AUTH", "YTJlOGE2MTktYmQzZC00NmZmLTlmMzctZDY2ZjBmOWM2YjQw");

            WKUserScript cookieScript = new WKUserScript(
                new NSString(p), WKUserScriptInjectionTime.AtDocumentEnd, false);
            userController.AddUserScript(cookieScript);
            userController.AddUserScript(script);
            var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration { UserContentController = userController };
            var webView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
            webView.NavigationDelegate = new NavigationDelegate();
            webView.Configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            webView.Configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;

            webView.ScrollView.ScrollEnabled = true;
            webView.ScrollView.Bounces = false;
            webView.AllowsBackForwardNavigationGestures = false;
            var cookie = new NSHttpCookie(new Cookie() { Domain = "10.10.208.219", Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1000), Name = ".GTMS_AUTH", Value = "YTJlOGE2MTktYmQzZC00NmZmLTlmMzctZDY2ZjBmOWM2YjQw" });


            SetNativeControl(webView);

        }
        if (e.OldElement != null)
        {
            //userController.RemoveAllUserScripts();
            //userController.RemoveScriptMessageHandler("invokeAction");
            //var hybridWebView = e.OldElement as HybridWebView;
            //hybridWebView.Cleanup();
        }
        if (e.NewElement != null)
        {
            HybridWebView hybridWebView = e.NewElement as HybridWebView;


            var request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(new NSUrl(hybridWebView.Uri));       
            request.ShouldHandleCookies = true;
            Control.LoadRequest(request);
        }
    }


    public void DidReceiveScriptMessage(WKUserContentController userContentController, WKScriptMessage message)
    {
        Element.InvokeAction(message.Body.ToString());
    }

}
```

**Delegate** - I don't know if it is good :(

```
public class NavigationDelegate : WKNavigationDelegate
{

    public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationAction navigationAction, Action<WKNavigationActionPolicy> decisionHandler)
    {
        if (!requiresCookie(navigationAction))
        {
            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
            return;
        }

        if (navigationAction.Request.Headers.ObjectForKey(new NSString(".GTMS_AUTH")) != null)
        {
            NSUrl url = navigationAction.Request.Url;
            NSMutableUrlRequest request = new NSMutableUrlRequest(url);
            //NSDictionary cookieProps = new NSHttpCookie(".GTMS_AUTH", "ODg1ZWQwNTYtY2RkOC00NWI4LTlmNjUtODQ3ZWRjNzc3N2Jh", "/", "10.10.208.219");

            NSDictionary headerFields = NSDictionary.FromObjectsAndKeys(new object[] { ".GTMS_AUTH=YTJlOGE2MTktYmQzZC00NmZmLTlmMzctZDY2ZjBmOWM2YjQw" }, new object[] { "Cookie" });
            request.Headers = headerFields;
            request.ShouldHandleCookies = true;
            string p = "document.cookie = 'IsXamarin=true'; document.cookie = '.GTMS_AUTH=YTJlOGE2MTktYmQzZC00NmZmLTlmMzctZDY2ZjBmOWM2YjQw'; domain = '10.10.208.219'; path = '/'; ";

           // navigationAction.Request.SetValuesForKeysWithDictionary(headerFields);

            webView.EvaluateJavaScript(new NSString(p), null);

            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
            return;
        }


        decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.Allow);
    }

    public override void DecidePolicy(WKWebView webView, WKNavigationResponse navigationResponse, Action<WKNavigationResponsePolicy> decisionHandler)
    {

        decisionHandler(WKNavigationResponsePolicy.Allow);

    }

    public bool requiresCookie(WKNavigationAction wKNavigationAction)
    {
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: You can set the cookies using both JS and `NSMutableUrlRequest ` at initial time. JS may not be captured in `navigationAction.Request.Headers`. Also the key when you want to get cookies should be `Cookie`.

Comment: I'm trying with WKUserScript and set JS (document.cookie etc.) but it not work :/ whenever my website show login page :/

Comment: I mean move your code in DecidePolicy() about request.Headers to OnElementChanged() when you initialize the webview.

Comment: @akustycznyy  You got any workaround for this issue?